# Get CMS page description

Tags: php, template

I want to echo the description and title of the page.
I tried to load this by:

Name:

```
<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); ?>
```

Description:

```
<?php echo strip_tags($this->getDescription()) ?>
```

But it does not dispaly anything.
Do I need to load a helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMS page : To get the identifier of the current CMS page you can use

```
$current_identifier = Mage::getSingleton(‘cms/page’)->getIdentifier();
```

To get the Page Title :

```
$current_title = Mage::getSingleton(‘cms/page’)->getTitle();
```

To get the Page ID :

```
$current_id = Mage::getBlockSingleton(‘cms/page’)->getPage()->getId();
```

To get the page content:

```
$current_content = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getContent();
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but that does not display the title. Am I missing a helper at the top of the page?

Comment: Try this one Mage::getModel(’cms/page’)->getResource()->getCmsPageTitleByIdentifier(’YOUR_IDENTIFIER’);

Comment: how can I get content with remove magento code?

Answer (score 0):

Get Current CMS Page : Magento(CMS Pages Data)

```
$cms_id = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
$cms_title = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getTitle();
$cms_content = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getContent();
```

also you can try:-

```
$pageTitle = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('about-magento-demo-store', 'identifier')->getTitle();
```

**I hope this will help you.**

On a side note, it's good to mention that the `load` method actually accepts two parameters, where the second one is the field that you want to use to load your object:

```
public function load($id, $field=null)
{
    $this->_beforeLoad($id, $field);
    $this->_getResource()->load($this, $id, $field);
    $this->_afterLoad();
    $this->setOrigData();
    $this->_hasDataChanges = false;
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but that does not display the title. Am I missing a helper at the top of the page?

Comment: welcome dude...!!! i have tried and works fine so give you this...!@!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
<?php   
    $yourPageIdentifier = 'aboutus';
    $cmsPage = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($yourPageIdentifier,'identifier') 
    // get description
    echo $cmsPage->getDescription();
    // get title 
    echo $cmsPage->getTitle();
?>
```